# Sum retorna valor incorreto

Tags: mysql, sql

Quero somar todos os valores de duas colunas de cada tabela, mas quando eu faço o SELECT Sum ele misteriosamente adiciona mais uma casa decimal exemplo 10 + 10 = 200.00

```
SELECT sum(jan.pl_proposta) AS totalJanProp, sum(jan.pl_realizado) AS totalJanReali,
sum(fev.pl_proposta) AS fev_proposta, sum(fev.pl_realizado) AS fev_realizado
FROM tbl_janeiro jan, tbl_fevereiro fev
WHERE jan.pl_ano = 2021
AND fev.pl_ano = 2021;
```

[image: Valores do Sum]

resultado dos valores

[image: Tabela janeiro]

Tabela de janeiro

Estou fazendo dessa forma porque não quero fazer um SELECT para cada mês, teria que ter 12 SELECT e 12 listas para receber os valores, não sei o que está acontecendo para ocasionar isso, se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço muito...
Também tentei usar o INNER JOIN para chamar as outras tabelas, mas acontece o mesmo erro.

Comment: E a tabela de fevereiro? Não tem registros?

Comment: Tem sim, as mesmas categorias do janeiro, com valores diferentes

Comment: o problema é que está somando multiplas vezes, você adicinou duas tabelas no `from ` mas não relacionou, então está fazendo um cartesiado... quando se usa mais de uma tabela tem relaciona-las, seja com join ou no where

Comment: Esclareceu minha duvida abaixo muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Consegui Fazer o código funcionar como deveria, adicionei o INNER JOIN e o ON,
mas alguém poderia me explicar porque eu preciso do ON, sendo que a tabela janeiro não precisa estar ligada à tabela Fevereiro.

```
 SELECT sum(jan.pl_proposta) AS totalJanProp, sum(jan.pl_realizado) AS totalJanReali, 
                sum(fev.pl_proposta) AS fev_proposta, sum(fev.pl_realizado) AS fev_realizado 
                FROM tbl_janeiro jan 
                INNER JOIN tbl_fevereiro fev 
                ON jan.pl_categoria = fev.pl_categoria 
                WHERE jan.pl_ano = 2021 AND fev.pl_ano = 2021;
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).